# Angular: Adding a component before another component the modular way

Tags: angular

I have an architectural question:

I have a module A with component called `a` which includes `component-a2` like following:

```
<!-- in file a.component.html -->
<component-a2></component-a2>
```

Now I create a module B with a component called `component-b`. I want to display this component right before `component-a2` but without modifying the file `a.component.html` or anything outside of module B. Instead, I'm looking for some Angular mechanism where I can hook right out of module B.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use routing and a router outlet? Or the dynamic component loader? https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Sounds like you want to be using Ng-content. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

Comment: Thank you @DeborahK. The dynamic component loader is getting very close to what I want to do. I have to define an explicit extension point instead of a generic one, but that is ok for my purpose.